# How to disable "scroll" behavior in UITableView when we insert them to a scrollView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I want to put a UITableView in a scrollView.

I want the full UITableView there.

Hence, I do not want UITableView to "scroll" around independently. I want the UITableView to be fully displayed inside the scrollView.

What would you do on my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable scrolling on your table view: `tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;`

Technically, your table view is a scroll view, so all of its properties are available.

Comment: I see. I will also need to know the size of all the cells added together in the tableView and set the size to that. I suppose.

Comment: That would be convenient - and it should be fairly easy for static content. Maybe even sizeToFit works - but I've never tried that.